# Petfinder api and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to pull petfinder api but i am new to this. I am having issues as nothing is showing up on the page. Here is the link and you can see there is data

```
http://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom?key=b6ba5a567c1e4f543b3c8a4b7ae0cf76&shelterid=KY305&output=full&format=json
```

Here is the code i have in the js file. You can see i ma just trying to add the description and trying for photo on just one the large size photos  with ID 1 .

Sorry for such a newbie question. Not sure why it is not showing . Here is my test site

http://www.wpcreations.net/matt/petsearch.html

admins / users - I will remove the live links and key once i figure out the issue. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var petfinderAPI = "http://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom?format=json&key=b6ba5a567c1e4f543b3c8a4b7ae0cf76&callback?";

    var petfinderOPT ={

        animal:"dog",
        shelterid:"KY305",
        output:"basic",
        //format:"json"

    };


    function displayInfo(data){

        var infoHTML = '<ul>';
        $.each(data.pet,function(i, pets){
        infoHTML += '<p> ' +  pets.description + ' <p>';
        //infoHTML += '<img src = " ' + photo.options.media.photos.photo + '"></a><li>';
        });
        infoHTML += '</ul>';

        $('#petfinderInfo').html(infoHTML);

        }

    $.getJSON(petfinderAPI,petfinderOPT,displayInfo)
  .done(function(petApiData) { alert('Data retrieved!'); })
  .error(function(err) { alert('Error retrieving data!'); 
});


}); //end ready function
```

Here is a snippet from pet finder api doc - Cross-Domain Support (JSONP)

The Petfinder API supports JSONP for cross-domain JavaScript requests. When making any request that is in JSON format, the callback parameter may be added to denote that this is a JSONP request. The value for the callback parameter should be a unique string.

Below is a basic example of a JSONP request, using jQuery. Here the callback=? query string parameter is required to specify that it is a JSONP call. jQuery will replace the '?' within the query string with a unique time-stamped value (i.e. 'jQuery110206092635430395603_1391456463806').

```
$.getJSON('http://api.petfinder.com/my.method?format=json&key=12345&callback=?')
  .done(function(petApiData) { alert('Data retrieved!'; })
  .error(function(err) { alert('Error retrieving data!'); 
});
```

Here is link to petfinder api . I am not sure if you have to join site or not https://www.petfinder.com/developers/api-docs#request-format

Comment: You got to check your console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom?format=json&key=b6ba5a567c1e4f543b3c8a4b7ae0cf76&callback?&animal=dog&shelterid=KY305&output=basic. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.wpcreations.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Also there doc says jsonp is supported . i do not know how to get around that. I did try chrome which has a plugin that gets around it .But nothing shows ...https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Do they offer JSONP or ask them to enable CORS

Comment: i posted what it said in the doc and i do not see the issue as they have stated you can.

Comment: And getJSON docs for jsonp http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp says use $.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you but i have figured out what was wrong and used ajax to pull the info.  You can close this answer but here is some of the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom?key=longkeygoeshere&shelterid=KY305&output=full&format=json';
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        data : {},
        url : url+'&callback=?' ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {              
            // stores result
            var result = '';

            var petfinder = data.petfinder;
            var infoHTML = '<ul>';
            infoHTML += '<li>';
            infoHTML += '<strong>Description</strong><br>';
            infoHTML += petfinder.pet.description['$t'];
            infoHTML += '</li>';

            infoHTML += '</li>';

            infoHTML += '</ul>';
            // return infoHTML;
            $('#petfinderInfo').html(infoHTML);

            // $('#petfinderInfo').html(petfinder.pet.description['$t']);
            // 
            console.log(petfinder);
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
});

</script>
```