# Pet Finder API Special Characters To Display

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api

I am new to stack overflow and since I don't have many rep points yet I couldn't comment where I wanted ([related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738177/petfinder-api-and-jquery)) so I needed to open a new question.

Question: Why do I need to add ['$t'] at the end of the JSON key to get the value to display?

This ajax is calling the Pet Finder API.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    url: url + '&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

      //declare and assign JSON array of data results
      var petfinder = data.petfinder.pets.pet;

      for (var i = 0; i < petfinder.length; i++) {
        var infoDiv = $("<div>")
        var name = $("<div>").html("<b>Name: </b>" + petfinder[i].name['$t']);
        var animal = $("<div>").html("<b>Animal Type: </b>" + petfinder[i].animal['$t']);
        var age = $("<div>").html("<b>Age: </b>" + petfinder[i].age['$t']);
        var sex = $("<div>").html("<b>Sex: </b>" + petfinder[i].sex['$t']);
        var size = $("<div>").html("<b>Size: </b>" + petfinder[i].size['$t'] + "<br><hr><br>");

        infoDiv.append(animal)
        infoDiv.append(name)
        infoDiv.append(age)
        infoDiv.append(sex)
        infoDiv.append(size)

        // return infoHTML;
        $('#petfinderInfo').append(infoDiv);
      }
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
      alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response from Pet Finder API looks something like this (this is part of the actual response):

```
"status":{
    "message":{},
    "code":{
        "$t":"100"
    }
}
```

As you can see one of the keys inside the code object property is $t which stores the status code (as it seems), so in order to get the value 100 you need to access the object using `["status"]["code"]["$t"]` alternatively you could access it using `status.code.$t`.

Your code is completely fine and is not related to anything, it's just the way the API is constructed and what it is using as keys, if you're asking why it's done this way, then you should probably ask the developers of the API, might be part of their design process with hopefully some clever logic behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I wasn't sure if I was missing something with JQuery in terms of understanding it :)